# Setting up a local Sonar (server) vs having all the plugins checkstyles,pmd,findbugs in eclipse

Tags: java, continuous-integration, sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd

We are working on developing web application as a team, and decided to be compliant to sonar rules in our Continuous Integration Server before committing the code.
After thinking we had 2 plans:

1. Having local sonar in every one's system and integrating that to eclipse using SonarQube plugin.
2. We can add checkstyles,Pmd,findbugs plugins to eclipse and use the same rules as in sonar.

May I know Pros and Cons of each plan.

Plan 2 is effort less and economic and no need to run Sonar server in every system
but does plan 2 can perform as much as sonar?

After doing some research on them what I found is Individually Checkstyles plugin uses ANTLR, PMD uses JAVACC and Findbugs works on bytecode instead of working on source code that means all the three plugins individually uses Java Virtual Machine for processing and producing results,Sonar does the same as well(runs on JVM) and one more thing I found is if we are using them individually rules overlap might happen.
So my opinion is Using Sonar is better if we are working on big things for long run.

Comment: Enforce the minimum quality-check rules centrally, provide (and support) the developers with the tools, documentation and infrastructure to deliver code of maximum quality.

Answer (score 3):

Good question! The answer depends on how much effort you are willing to spend. Let me describe two alternatives. Both will include only *a single, central SonarQube server*, because running individual SonarQube servers has too many problems (exploding license costs once you run a commercial plugin; too much admin overhead; high startup time).

Rule overlap happens in all cases, so you will have to deal with that no matter what.

**Easiest**

The easiest setup is one central SonarQube server that everyone uses via the SonarQube plugin. You would *not* use any other individual analysis tools locally.

- Little work, because you administer only the central server, and all developers automatically get everything from there. This pays off for upgrades in particular, because only the SonarQube admin needs to do anything.
- Very high alignment of local analyses with continuous integration analysis (usually 100%). So people have a very low chance of seeing warnings in the SonarQube web GUI that they don't see in their IDEs.
- You can use the SonarQube supplied special detectors locally. This is a small advantage only, because they are mostly reimplementations of the Checkstyle, PMD, and FindBugs detectors. It may be a reason for you still.
- Performance is good. SonarQube can check only the changed files, so it is quite fast. Also, developers perform local analyses which do not upload data to the server, so you lose no time doing that and you do not spam the central database. (Checkstyle, FindBugs and PMD will still run locally "under the hood" if you choose any of their rules in SonarQube.)

**Gold Standard**

The gold standard is one central SonarQube server that is used only by the continuous integration system. Developers would *not* use SonarQube, but individual analysis tools which are configured according to a central configuration supplied by the person who maintains the SonarQube quality profiles. On the downside, this is much more work, because you must maintain not one but usually four configurations (Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs, SonarQube). (And yes, the [PermaLinks](http://www.sonarqube.org/eclipse-checkstyle-sonar-an-emerging-source-code-management-solution/) won't help in this case.) Developers would have to check the SonarQube Web GUI every now and then to make sure nothing escaped their local checks.

OK, more work, but what makes it better?

- You get *way more features*, because the rules applied locally can use the full feature set of each individual tool. You are not limited to the feature set that SonarQube supports. For instance, at the time of this writing, SonarQube supports only Checkstyle 5.6, whereas Checkstyle 5.8 is already out. So you'd miss out on a lot of new checks and bug fixes. Using Checkstyle directly on the local machines, your code will already be compliant to your future CI rules that you can put in place once SonarQube also moves to Checkstyle 5.8.
- Better usability because you get to use Checkstyle [custom messages](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Custom_messages). This way, your developers can see a message like `Member 'theField' must start with a lowercase 'm'` instead of `Identifier 'theField' did not match pattern '^m[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'`. Especially for complex regexes, this makes a huge difference for the acceptance of your quality control system.
- You can use plugins for the individual tools that don't feature a SonarQube plugin yet. Again more checks!
- Performance is also very good. All three tools have very good IDE integration, so they also run fast and only on changed files.

Comment: But the recent versions of sonar (say 4.4 and 4.5)don't have an option of uploading/applying customized checkstyles,pmds etc...Only there is a provision to upload findbugs file only and they mentioned in their site that they are not going to support user profiles(customizable)
please refer the following urls mentioned
1.www.sonarqube.org/already-158-checkstyle-and-pmd-rules-

deprecated-by-sonarqube-java-rules/
2.http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin

What to do ?Proceed with sonar in built profiles or use older versions of sonar or using eclipse plugins(checkstyles and pmds etc)

Comment: You must [create your quality profiles](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) in SonarQube. I don't think you can just upload something. But that has nothing to do with the options in your question or the options in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the size of your team, the more probable you will have problems with local configuration. I remember once I installed a new softare and it worked only with a JDK 32 bits, so I uninstalled my JDK 64 bits for a JDK 32 bits. After that, I had some Sonar analysis with a problem of memory space due to the changed JVM.

Performance is, as always, a question of configuration and charge. How many applications/lines of code do you want to analyze vs. what is your server/database/.. configuration.

Regards.